# Finding a partial text in a range of cells and if found, return an X

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like excel to look for a partial text "Brigitte" in a row of cells and return "X" if found. So if in a range of cells, containing several names in each cell, the name "Brigitte" appears, than I want excel to return an X, if not than I want nothing returned.
I have been looking an looking and haven't found the solution so far.
Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

Comment: I tried this: but it doesn't work: =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Brigitte",'FY15 Germany & Benelux Projects'!K2:O2)),"X","")

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different approach than [pnuts' one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28233348/finding-a-partial-text-in-a-range-of-cells-and-if-found-return-an-x/28233615#28233615) would be using `COUNTIF` instead of `MATCH`.

```
=IF((COUNTIF('FY15 Germany & Benelux Projects'!K2:O2,"*Brigitte*")>0),"X","")
```

Comment: @pnuts Thanks for the hint! I didn't check OP's formula properly nor did I know this can be changed in settings.

Answer (score 0):

Please try something like this:

```
=IF(MATCH("*Brigitte*",'FY15 Germany & Benelux Projects'!K2:O2,0)>0,"X","")
```

Comment: It works!!! The only issue now is that when "Brigitte" doesn't appear at all in any cell, than excel return #N/A instead on Nothing. I actually want excel to return a Blank cell.

Comment: I unfortunately still get the N/A but also now the result I get if "Brigitte" is found is not "X" but "True". Even though in the IF formula the result states "X"....

Comment: Hi @Pnuts, I tried again and it finally worked! You solved my issue, thank you so much!!!